# How can I trigger modal boxes using the following javascript code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, popup, simplemodal

Hey guys I need just a little bit of help with this.
So I have modal boxes hiding on my page and when I click on them using the video platform VERSE they work perfectly.

My questions is: How can I call the same modal boxes if I wan to call them from a regular link or button on the page.

Here is the sample:
http://digitalfeast.com/clients/nccv/ncc-verse.html

Here is my Javascript code:

```
(function() {
(function() {
  window.onload = function() {

    var frame = document.getElementsByName("verse-iframe")[0].contentWindow;

    // Variables below (i.e. "menu-1") reference div id from your markup
    function receiveMessage(event) {

      var data = (typeof event.data === "String") ? JSON.parse(event.data) : event
      var modalWindow1 = document.getElementById("ruben-1");
      var modalWindow2 = document.getElementById("ruben-2");
      var modalWindow3 = document.getElementById("menu-3");
      var modalWindow4 = document.getElementById("menu-4");

      // Variables below (i.e. "menu-1") reference the unique callback names entered for your hotspots in the Verse editor
      if (data.data["identifier"] === "ruben-1") {
        modalWindow1.style.display = "block";
      }
      if (data.data["identifier"] === "ruben-2") {
        modalWindow2.style.display = "block";
      }
      if (data.data["identifier"] === "menu-3") {
        modalWindow3.style.display = "block";
      }
      if (data.data["identifier"] === "menu-4") {
        modalWindow4.style.display = "block";
      }
    }

    var closeBtns = document.getElementsByClassName("modal-close");

    for (var i = 0; i < closeBtns.length; i++) {
      var btn = closeBtns[i];
      btn.onclick = function (event) {
        event.target.parentNode.parentNode.style.display = "none";
        frame.postMessage({action: "play"}, "*");
        };
    }

    window.addEventListener('message', receiveMessage);
    var frame = document.getElementsByName("verse-iframe")[0].contentWindow;

  };
}());
}());
```

Comment: What's with the double IIFEs?  With an onload inside it...  Those IIFE's are doing nothing for you in this code snippet.

Comment: Also redeclaring `frame`. A cut-n-paste mini-edit situation?

Comment: Hey Randy, you're right! I'll remove the double IIFEs, also the "frame" declaration was just a cut and paste from SublimeText.

Answer (score 0):

Given your code, all you need to do is send the window a message using the Messaging API inside your button click handler.
Your event listener will then execute the `receiveMessage` function and open your model for `ruben-1`.

```js
window.onload = () => {
  document.querySelector('[data-modal="ruben-1"]').addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    let postData = {
      identifier: e.target.dataset.modal
    };
    window.postMessage(postData, "*");
  });

  window.addEventListener('message', m => {
    alert(m.data.identifier);
  });
}
```

```html
<button data-modal="ruben-1">Ruben-1 Video</button>
```

Comment: Hey Randy, I removed the extra IIFEs and "frame declaration". where exactly should I put the code above? Also should I just add the ID# to my <a href="#ruben-1">Call Modal</a> to call my modal box?

Comment: You said you wanted to "click a button" to launch the modal, so this code would go into your "click" handler for that button. I'll update my example to include a representative button.

Comment: Thanks Randy, I really appreciate your help! :P

Comment: For some reason its not working, when I put the: 

document.querySelector('[data-modal="ruben-1"]').addEventListenter("click", (e)=> {
    let postData = {identifier:e.target.dataset.modal};
    window.postMessage(postData, "*");
}

within the window.onload it automatically opens the popup without me clicking the button.

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Please look at the example I just added to my answer and compare your code. This is what you should expect.